How to correctly change the display language in Windows 11?
I have a computer running Windows 11 where I set the display language (Idioma para Mostrar) to Argentine Spanish (Español (Argentina)) but when I look in the settings, it appears as Mexican Spanish. Any ideas why and/or how to fix it?


Run get-winsystemlocale and get-culture in Powershell. What is returned? It should be es-AR rather than es-MX.
